# How to change DTPickers date format to yyyy/mm/dd?

Tags: vb6

i tried this in form load event :

DTPicker1.Format = dtpCustom

DTPicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

That didnt work.
when i saved it to my database, it turned into dd/mm/yyyy.

I tested it with a textbox, i sent the value to a textbox, it gave me the same dd/mm/yyyy.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The `Format` and `CustomFormat` properties are about how values are displayed or entered into the `DTPicker` *user interface*.  The `Value` property is of type `Date`, which has no "format" since it is not a character string, and in a decent DBMS this remains true - contrary to the incorrect answer posted below.  You seem to be tripping over implicit data type coercion.

Comment: @bob77. Yeah, i use vb6 string manipulation to get the correct format for mysql, i solve it by myself. i dont get the downvote either

Answer (score 0):

The standard format of Date field type in databases is normally: 
MM/DD/YYYY HH:NN:SS
(Unless expressly indicated, where database allows to set a different format); this is depend from database type.

I.e. Access doesn't allows to store date on other formats.

You must set the custom format after load data using Format() function:

```
Text1.Text = Format$(YourRecordset!YourData, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: If a DBMS supports an actual Date type, then it has no "format."  For example Jet Red MDB databases store the Date type as a Double value with a special interpretation.  Jet SQL Date (date and time) literals do indeed follow the invariant locale format and are delimited by `#` characters but that string of characters has nothing to do with the storage format.

Comment: uhhh...i want to change the format of date generated by DTpickers in vb6, not changing the format of dates already stored in database